# WhiteBox tools error 'Incorrect parameter value for inputs' when running 'LidarJoin' tool

Tags: qgis, lidar, whitebox-tools

I have 130 LAZ files I want to join into 10 or so files to make a DEM, these are all bare earth, I'm attempting to use the LidarJoin tool from WhiteBox tools, and I get an error upon running: 'Incorrect parameter value for inputs', see attached screenshot.[image]

Any ideas? I can run the LidarDigitalSurfaceModel tool fine so I know it isn't related to installation issues, or file path issues.

Thanks

EDIT: After trying to run the same tool in batch mode there is a longer message, something about there being no header? As this is compressed LAZ data I tried the LAZToLAS tool, only discover it doesn't support LAS as an output!?? WHAT?? Good lord.
Running the LidarInfo tool I can see that there clearly is header info WBT can read?...

I've spent 8 hours fighting this, I'm glad I didn't pay for it, as the only tool I want to use I can't get working ha ha ha!

Edit 2: Also the command line doesn't work:[image]